The relation between Hodge bundles with metric and polarized variation of Hodge structures
Recently I've been reading Simpson's paper "constructing variations of Hodge structure using Yang-Mills theory and applications to uniformization, 1988, JAMS". On page 898 he mentioned about the relation between Hodge bundles with metric and polarized VHS which I am not aware of.
A polarized VHS is a smooth vector bundle $E = \oplus_{p+q=n} E^{p,q}$ with a flat connection $d$ and Hermitian pairing $Q$ such that
(1) $d$ is compatible with $Q$;
(2) $d = \partial + \theta + \bar{\partial} + \theta^*$ which map $A^0(X,E^{p,q})$ to $A^{1,0}(X,E^{p,q}),A^{1,0}(X,E^{p-1,q+1}),A^{0,1}(X,E^{p,q}),A^{0,1}(X,E^{p+1,q-1})$ respectively;
(3)$h(u,v):= \sum_{p+q=n}(-1)^q Q(u^{p,q},v^{p,q})$ is a Hermitian metric, called the Hodge metric.
A system of Hodge bundles is a direct sum of holomorphic vector bundles $E = \oplus_{p+q=n} E^{p,q}$ with a morphism $\theta : E^{p,q} \rightarrow E^{p-1,q+1} \otimes \Omega_X^1$ such that $\theta^2 = 0$.
Clearly from this definition one can deduce that $E = \oplus_{p+q=n} E^{p,q}$ is a system of Hodge bundles. What confuses me the most is how a system of Hodge bundles with metric induces a polarized VHS? In Simpson's paper he said "Given a metric $K$ we get a metric connection $D_K$ and this preserves the indefinite form $<u,v>_K = (\sqrt{-1})^{p-q} (u,v)_K$ for $u,v \in E^{p,q}$. It also satisfies Griffiths transversality condition." which I cannot verify. If the connection is flat how to obtain a polarized VHS?
